# C++ search directories and files

Tags: c++, file, directory

Can someone tell me if there is a library built in C++ that I can use to get a list of files and directories? I've looked around and I see people using dirent.h but I need to download it(i think).

Thanks

P.S. I've looked at the fstream, but thats only for reading and outputting files as far as i know.

FORGOT TO MENTION. I DO NOT WANT TO DOWNLOAD ANYTHING, I JUST WANT TO SEE IF THERE IS A LIBRARY THAT IS BUILT WITHIN C++ THAT I CAN USE STRAIGHT OFF THE BAT. THIS IS FOR WINDOWS ASWELL

Comment: Which platform are you using? C++ itself is platform agnostic so you should provide this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Boost Filesystem` library.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Some nice samples are also provided at the link.

EDIT:

Without downloading a 3rd party library, there is no portable way to do it. For windows you can use [CFileFind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class from MFC.

Comment: do I have to download this library? to use it? says cannot find file... using VS2008

Comment: Yes, you do need to download boost.

Comment: @Danny I updated my answer, this should work without any additional downloads.

Answer (score 3):

How about [Boost::Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm)? Supports [directory iteration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration) and is portable.

Answer (score 2):

**Using namespace std::filesystem** is available in **visual studio 2017** you have in **#include**

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
void Files_in_Directory();

fs::path path_Copy_Directory = "E:\Folder";
fs::path path_Paste_Directory = "E:\Folder1";
int main()
{
Files_in_Directory()
return 0;
}
void Files_in_Directory()
{
 for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path_Copy_Directory))
 {
  std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
   
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since others already mentioned [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) there are also other alternatives. Almost every C++ framework has some way to list directories and files. Like [wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxdir.html#wxdir) or [poco](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.DirectoryIterator.html) and there are many more.

Regarding `dirent.h`. It is a [standard C Posix library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h) so on Posix compatible systems it should be available. For Windows you can also get it [here](http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php) and it includes instructions on how to use it.

After your edit:

On Windows you can use things like [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and then you don't have to download anything. But it only works on Windows. It is not build in C++.